# Why class Imagick not found in laravel 7.0?

Tags: php, laravel

I had install Imagick:

```
download:
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/imagick/3.4.3/php_imagick-3.4.3-7.2-ts-vc15-x64.zip
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-vc15-x64.zip
extract php_imagick.dll to ext/
extract ImageMagick-7.0.7 to one path
ADD ImageMagick-7.0.7/bin to SYSTEM PATH
ADD "extension=imagick" in php.ini
ADD LoadFile "/yourImageMagickPath/bin/CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll" in httpd.conf
```

Result of `phpinfo`:
[image]

I try test in controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "magick:rose");
        $im->setImageFormat("png");
        $im->roundCorners(5,3);
        $type=$im->getFormat();
        header("Content-type: $type");
        echo $im->getimageblob();
        return view('home');
    }
```

It occur error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Imagick' not found
```

Why class  Imagick not found in laravel 7.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Imagick' not found` means that `Imagick` is not in the namespace `App\Http\Controllers`. If you want to use `Imagick` you need to prepend it with the "root" namespace `\`. Change

```
$im = new Imagick();
```

to

```
$im = new \Imagick();
```

Comment: Or add after "namespace" line "use \Imagick;"

Comment: not working for me